# How are logical operators performed and measured on the surface code, in a defect-free way?

Tags: entanglement, measurement, error-correction, stabilizer-code

I am reading about the surface code and I am still not sure how to perform and measure logical operators, such as $X_L$ or $Z_L$, without creating defects. Suppose I stabilise my qubit array into a quiescent state $|\psi\rangle$, knowing all stabilizer eigenvalues. Performing $X_L$ on the qubit array does change the quiescent state non-trivially, but the syndrome remains equal. So by stabilizer measurements alone, I cannot detect that I applied the logical $X$ operator. So how *do* you perform such an operation, in a way that it can be read out?

Extra question, how do you even prepare an eigenstate of these operators, i.e. $|0\rangle_L, |1\rangle_L, |+\rangle_L, |-\rangle_L$ to begin with?

All the answers I find require defects.

Answer (score 3):

> I am still not sure how to perform [...] $X_L$ or $Z_L$

To perform logical X or logical Z in any code, apply the Pauli operators of the observable. This is always fault tolerant, in any stabilizer code. If the X operator is a line of qubits going from the bottom boundary to the top boundary, apply X to the qubits along that line and you'll do the X operator.

Actually, for a stabilizer code like the surface code, it's simply a waste of time to perform any Pauli operator on the quantum computer except for purposes such as spin echo. You can just update the control system's Pauli frame instead, which is faster and more flexible and more accurate. Pauli gates are never important to whether or not something is fault tolerant, they're just distracting finicky details.

> how do you even prepare an eigenstate of these operators

$X_L$ and $Z_L$ observables are prepared and measured transversally. To prepare $|+\rangle$, initialize every data qubit in the patch into $|+\rangle$. To measure $Z_L$, measure every data qubit in the patch in the Z basis.

$Y_L$ is prepared and measured by [moving corner twists within the patch](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.07395).

$|T\rangle$ is prepared by distillation.

Arbitrary signle qubit states are prepared by approximate decomposition into a series of H and T gates.

> from https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.06709
>
> [image]

Comment: Moderators, I'm sorry I think someone has hacked my account and answered some questions using ChatGPT. I'm really sorry for this unhealthy discussions. I'm attemoting to delete this account.

Comment: @Someone I'm assuming this comment refers to the other (deleted) answer, and not this specific one you've commented on. Which I did write myself (e.g. ChatGPT isn't capable of embedding screenshots of papers into its output).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So to apply $X_L$, one can perform $X$-operators on the entire line of qubits going from the bottom boundary to the top boundary? But that does not change the syndrome, so how can we distinguish between the $|0\rangle_L$ and $X_L|0\rangle_L=|1\rangle_L$ state in principle?

Comment: @JoJo The goal is to NOT distinguish 0 from 1 under normal operation (except measurement). Otherwise the qubit wouldn't survive.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You're saying that under measurement, you *do* have to distinguish 0 from 1. How is this done if the measurement syndromes always give the same result? Just reading out the data qubits themselves?

Comment: @JoJo yes to measure you read out all the data qubits not just the stabilizers.

Comment: Alright! What I was confused with, is that if you initialise all data qubits in the $|0\rangle$ state, then the state after stabilisation becomes a multi-qubit Bell-like superposition state. For example: 2 qubits stabilised by $XX$ and $ZZ$. Initialisation in $|00\rangle$ gives, after stabilisation, $|00\rangle\pm|11\rangle$, depending on what syndrome you measure. How is this distinguishable from the logical 1 state, which is prepared as $|11\rangle$, and after stabilisation yields $|11\rangle\pm|00\rangle$?

Comment: @JoJo 2 qubits stabilized by XX and ZZ have no logical degree of freedom (2-2=0). Try four qubits stabilized by ZZII, IIZZ, and XXXX (4-3=1).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, for 4 qubits it works. Depending on the eigenvalues of the stabilisers, we get a basis with 2 elements, the logical 0 and 1 state. It's clear for me now, thanks!

Comment: I still don't get how 0 and 1 are distinguished. Let's say I have 2 qubits stabilised by $S=X_1X_2$. Then putting in the $|00\rangle$ state and stabilising gives me $|0\rangle_X (|00\rangle+|11\rangle)|0\rangle_X + |1\rangle_X (|00\rangle-|11\rangle)|0\rangle_X$, while putting in $|11\rangle$ and stabilising gives $|0\rangle_X (|00\rangle+|11\rangle)|0\rangle_X - |1\rangle_X (|00\rangle-|11\rangle)|0\rangle_X$. Upon measuring the syndrome, they give the same states. So let's say I start with $|0\rangle_L$, and want to apply $X_L$. How do I possibly know I end up with $|1\rangle_L$?

Comment: @JoJo I repeat: you aren't supposed to know if it's 0 or 1. That would be a measurement. This is a quantum bit. Measuring it destroys it. You only want to measure it when you want to measure it, not when you're just trying to rotate it.

Comment: Yeah no sure, I get that. But if you initialise in the 0 state, and you apply $X_L$, then you should end up in the 1 state. This is something you want to verify in experiments, for example, to check if the operation indeed succeeded according to theory. So I get that reading out stabilisers gives you no indication whether you're in 0 or 1, but when you read out the data qubits you have to retrieve information somehow that you applied an $X_L$, no? If reading out the data qubits gives you the same state whether it's logical 0 or 1, how can you distinguish between $X_L$ or $I_L$?

Comment: @JoJo Check with a simulator. The states are distinguishable if you measure all the data qubits.